# Xarray - Resample by hourly to daily on timezone-aware time dimension

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have a xarray DataArray named `da_ffdi_sel_utc` with `time`, `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions.

```
 xarray.DataArray 'FFDI' (time: 48   latitude: 2   longitude: 2)

 longitude (longitude) float32         145.34322 145.38107
 latitude  (latitude)  float32         -37.39728 -37.361225
 time      (time)      datetime64[ns]  1972-01-20T00:00:00, 1972-01-20T01:00:00, 1972-01-20T02:00:00 ... 1972-01-21T23:00:00
```

As the `time` coordinates are in UTC while I need to resample the FFDI values by 24 hours and get max() in the Australia Eastern Standard Time (UTC+10); so the resampled `time` coordinates will need to be 1972-01-20, 1972-01-21 and 1972-01-22.

What I have tried is:

```
# Create a timezone aware datatime
ds_time_austtime = pd.date_range('1972-01-20T11:00:00.000000000', '1972-01-22T11:00:00.000000000', freq='1H', closed='left', name="time", tz='Australia/Melbourne')  #timezone aware
print(ds_time_austtime)

    DatetimeIndex(['1972-01-20 11:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 12:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 13:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 14:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 15:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 16:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 17:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 18:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 19:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 20:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 21:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-20 22:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-20 23:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 00:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 01:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 02:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 03:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 04:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 05:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 06:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 07:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 08:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 09:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 10:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 11:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 12:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 13:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 14:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 15:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 16:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 17:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 18:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 19:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 20:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 21:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-21 22:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-21 23:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 00:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-22 01:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 02:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-22 03:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 04:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-22 05:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 06:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-22 07:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 08:00:00+11:00',
       '1972-01-22 09:00:00+11:00', '1972-01-22 10:00:00+11:00'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns, Australia/Melbourne]', name='time', freq='H')


# Create a new Dataset with the same Lat and Lon and FFDI as da_ffdi_sel_utc but time is from the new data as above
ds_ffdi_sel_aest = xr.Dataset()
ds_ffdi_sel_aest.coords['longitude'] = ('longitude', da_ffdi_sel_utc['longitude'])
ds_ffdi_sel_aest.coords['latitude'] = ('latitude', da_ffdi_sel_utc['latitude'])
ds_ffdi_sel_aest.coords['time'] = ('time', ds_time_austtime)
ds_ffdi_sel_aest['FFDI'] = (('time', 'latitude', 'longitude'), da_ffdi_sel_utc.values)

print(ds_ffdi_sel_aest['time'])
array([64713600000000000, 64717200000000000, 64720800000000000,
   64724400000000000, 64728000000000000, 64731600000000000,
   64735200000000000, 64738800000000000, 64742400000000000,
   64746000000000000, 64749600000000000, 64753200000000000,
   64756800000000000, 64760400000000000, 64764000000000000,
   64767600000000000, 64771200000000000, 64774800000000000,
   64778400000000000, 64782000000000000, 64785600000000000,
   64789200000000000, 64792800000000000, 64796400000000000,
   64800000000000000, 64803600000000000, 64807200000000000,
   64810800000000000, 64814400000000000, 64818000000000000,
   64821600000000000, 64825200000000000, 64828800000000000,
   64832400000000000, 64836000000000000, 64839600000000000,
   64843200000000000, 64846800000000000, 64850400000000000,
   64854000000000000, 64857600000000000, 64861200000000000,
   64864800000000000, 64868400000000000, 64872000000000000,
   64875600000000000, 64879200000000000, 64882800000000000], dtype=object)

# Do resample by time and get max daily FFDI from hourly FFDIs
da_ffdi_sel_aest_daily_max = ds_ffdi_sel_aest['FFDI'].resample(time='1D').max('time')
```

Then I was encountered by the following error:

```
~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_scipy_3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    531                 observed=observed,
    532                 mutated=self.mutated,
--> 533                 dropna=self.dropna,
    534             )
    535 

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_scipy_3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    683     # a passed-in Grouper, directly convert
    684     if isinstance(key, Grouper):
--> 685         binner, grouper, obj = key._get_grouper(obj, validate=False)
    686         if key.key is None:
    687             return grouper, [], obj

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_scipy_3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in _get_grouper(self, obj, validate)
   1440     def _get_grouper(self, obj, validate: bool = True):
   1441         # create the resampler and return our binner
-> 1442         r = self._get_resampler(obj)
   1443         r._set_binner()
   1444         return r.binner, r.grouper, r.obj

~\Anaconda3\envs\geo_scipy_3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py in _get_resampler(self, obj, kind)
   1433 
   1434         raise TypeError(
-> 1435             "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "
   1436             "TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, "
   1437             f"but got an instance of '{type(ax).__name__}'"

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

I am not sure if it is supported to do resample with timezone-aware time coordinates in xarray. Otherwise what is the best practice to do this?